# Corregir Consulta a varias tablas de MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas tardes a todos.

Tengo la siguiente consulta en MySQL que lo que me hace es mostrarme los tipos de tablas, procedures y funciones de MySQL de manera agrupada a cada base de datos:

```sql
SELECT
   `TABLE_SCHEMA`,
   `TABLE_TYPE`,
   COUNT(`TABLE_TYPE`) AS `CONTADOR_TIPO_TABLA`,
   `mysql`.`proc`.`type` AS `TIPO_SCRIPT`,
   COUNT(`mysql`.`proc`.`type`) AS `NUMERO_TIPO_SCRIPTS`
FROM
  `information_schema`.`TABLES`,
  `mysql`.`proc`
WHERE
  `information_schema`.`TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = `mysql`.`proc`.`db`
GROUP BY
  `TABLE_SCHEMA`,
  `TABLE_TYPE`,
  `type`
ORDER BY
  `TABLE_SCHEMA`,
  `CONTADOR_TIPO_TABLA`,
  `TABLE_TYPE`,
  `NUMERO_TIPO_SCRIPTS`,
  `TIPO_SCRIPT` ASC;
```

Cuando ejecuto la consulta me muestra los mismos numeros tanto en los totales de TIPO_SCRIPT y CONTADOR_TIPO_TABLA.

¿En que me estoy equivocando?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que estás intentando conseguir es algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
       `TABLE_SCHEMA` db,
       `TABLE_TYPE`,
       COUNT(`TABLE_TYPE`) AS `CONTADOR_TIPO_TABLA`
    FROM
      `information_schema`.`TABLES`
    GROUP BY
      `TABLE_SCHEMA`,
      `TABLE_TYPE`  
  ) c1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      `mysql`.`proc`.`db` db,
       `mysql`.`proc`.`type` AS `TIPO_SCRIPT`,
       COUNT(`mysql`.`proc`.`type`) AS `NUMERO_TIPO_SCRIPTS`
    FROM
      `mysql`.`proc`
    GROUP BY
      `mysql`.`proc`.`db`,`type`  
  ) c2 USING(db)
  ORDER BY
   db,
  `CONTADOR_TIPO_TABLA`,
  `TABLE_TYPE`;
```

Simplemente has combinado antes de agrupar, cuando lo que realmente necesitabas era agrupar y después combinar los resultados. De ahí que el conteo no coincidiera con lo que esperabas.

Espero que sea lo que buscabas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Gracias por la indicacion, David JP. Vi que lo he hecho mal.

Comment: Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)